# Read delimited separated flat files and convert to Java Model class / hashmap / any efficient way

Tags: java, etl, flat-file, parquet

I have different flat files which are delimiter separated. All the files are having different layout/schema [ different columns ]

**For example:**

**File 1:**

```
FirstName, LastName, MiddleName
```

**File 2:**

```
FullName,Qualification,Age
```

What i am trying to do is, write some generic code and which can convert any flat file and return as some Java model object or something else like HashMap having key value.

If i wanted to return as Java Model object,my model class should contain all the fields available in the files, which is like something hard coded.

All i have is file path and file layout/schema [above example], how can i write generic code for this?

Using HashMap is one option, but will it work on huge files like millions of records?

How ETL tools are reading files and processing records / applying transformations on any specific field ?

is there any efficient way to do this using Java 8 or Java 7?

Comment: Let's say each record contains 3 strings of 20 characters. That makes 120 bytes. Represented as a HashMap, you need some more bytes to hold the references to keys, values, entries, etc. Let's approximate to 240 bytes. Now let's say your file has 50 million records. That thus makes 50 million * 240 bytes, so approximately 50 * 240 MBs. So 12 GB of memory. That can be OK, or it might not, depending on the amount of memory you have, and on the correctness of my hypotheses. Usually it's best to process lines sequentially, and save them to another file or a database on the fly.

Comment: @JBNizet : Thanks for the great comment. Currently i am using Java Model and each file contains like 30 to 40 fields [ 25 fields will be common in all the files ], I am not sure if i use HashMap for 40 fields will that work or not...

Comment: Define "work". What are you concerned about? Time? Memory? Something else?

Comment: @JBNizet : I will try with HashMap as one option, but i would like to know is there any other alternative way to do this in Java?

Comment: Being generic doesn't mean you need to use a HashMap. You can still have a generic algorithm, using a custom strategy to transform each record into a specific Java object. But you still haven't told us what your concern was. What do you fear might "not work"?